# github pages does not include the repo name in the request for additional resources

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am trying to host a react app in github using github pages

I build the project and upload it to github

but when the index.html file request assets/index-d526a0c5.css and assets/index-c355192f.js it request the url

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/assets/index-c355192f.js`

but it must be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<repo-name>/assets/index-c355192f.js` to work

I even tried to but the css bundle file into style tag in index.html also for javascript but even that does not work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are building with `Create React App`,
Change the base path by setting `homepage` property in `package.json`.

```json
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

If you are using Webpack to build, set `output.publicPath` option in the config file.

```js
  output: {
    publicPath: ASSET_PATH,
  },
```

https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

By the way, you are trying to host the app on github pages.
You don't really need to specify the asset url as `raw.githubusercontent.com/...`, but `https://myusername.github.io/my-app/...`.

Comment: I am using create vite for react app instate of create react app, will I also use "homepage" with no modifications ?

Comment: I googled "create vite for react app", but there was no such kind of thing.

Comment: The point is, if you have config file, find public path or base path option.
If you do not, find option for the framework you use. @mahmoud2nasser2

Comment: thanks, I found it in the vite.config file 
which I have to add the 'base' attribute and site is to '/<repo-name>/'